# Oracle SQL, How to get group a field by one value and all other values combined?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get the count of a field and I would like that field to be grouped in two sets. One set is a specific value and the other set is all other values. Basically if my field is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], how would I group it so that I can get the count of all instances of '1' and the count of all other instances?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` statement:

```
select (case when field = 1 then '1' else 'All Other Values' end) as grp,
       count(*)
from t
group by (case when field = 1 then '1' else 'All Other Values' end);
```

Answer (score 0):

While Gordon's answer is more correct, you can also use Oracles decode:

```
SELECT DECODE(a.col, 1, 'first', 'other'), COUNT(*)
FROM atable a
GROUP BY DECODE(a.col, 1, 'first', 'other');
```

Comment: I would suggest `decode` should be discouraged in cases like this. A `case` expression is much easier to write, read and maintain. `decode` had its purpose in the old days, before `case` statements were introduced.